# Options for high-availablility, high-throughput bonding in Linux

Tags: linux, bonding, high-availability

When trying to configure high-availablity (HA) bonding in Linux that should also use the bandwidth available, I wonder what the options are:

The solution should ensure HA and optimal throughput (when all links are up) in a (simplified) scenario like this:

[image: Example Scenario for HA-Bonding]

So for example host **H1** has two interfaces **1** and **2**, also denoted as **H1.1** and **H1.2**.
Starting with a standard configuration like `active-backup` with `miimon` link monitoring there are these problems:

- Only one interface is used at a time
- If **S1.3** fails, both **H1.1** and **H1.2** will see a valid link, but **H1.1** could not reach **H2** then

So the first step was to use `arp_ip_target` for link monitoring to detect a possible inter-switch link (ISL) failure.

But still the problem is that only one of both host interfaces can be used at a time.
Do I tried to use `balance-tlb` instead of `active-backup`.
However it seems `balance-tlb` does not allow to use `arp_ip_target` for link monitoring.

So I wonder:
Is there a solution that provides both, high availability in case of any link failures *and* high bandwidth.

## Final note:

Conceptually **S1** and **S3** would be connected, too (just as **S2** and **S4**), but for illustration the example is simple enough, I hope.

Also I can configure the hosts, but not the switches.

Comment: We use `active-backup` bonding with `miimon` in our high availability setup, but higher bandwidth is not our goal. We want redundancy. I setup the computers with bonding and always connect them to two switches. Only one connection is active. So, no double bandwidth. There is no configuration needed on switches to support, but I think you need a connection between switches S1-S3 and S2-S4. Oh, I see you wrote there will be connections between switches. I am not sure what type of connection that is, because I am not expert in that and our network specialists always setup the switches.

Comment: Read this https://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/linux_unix/article.php/3850636/Understanding-NIC-Bonding-with-Linux.htm

Comment: @nobody If (as it seems to me) only `active-backup` supports ARP probes (and ARB probes are required to detect effective connectivity), then most "throughput modes" are not usable with HA. The article cited does not help much there. Also 802.3ad spanning multiple switches is very rare, and you need multiple switches for HA connectivity. After all the article does not add much over the basic bonding.txt.